# Customizing IMarker behavior

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to make an Eclipse plugin that will highlight certain lines certain colors based on outside input. Is there any way to specify the behavior of a new IMarker rather than rely on basic implementation of bookmarks, problems, etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the complete solution, but I think, I can give you some starting points.

The basic idea is to create custom annotations for your custom markers. You can define [your own marker types](http://eclipse.org/articles/Article-Mark%20My%20Words/mark-my-words.html), and register [constant formatting rules for it](http://cubussapiens.hu/2011/05/custom-markers-and-annotations-the-bright-side-of-eclipse/) (the latter one is a shameless link to one of my own blog posts). In this case, if your code creates the correct marker types, you can add the different formatting regarding the output.

On the other hand, if you have only a single problem type, I don't know the correct answer, but the Annotation Model Creation extension seems to be the answer. For details look at [the Eclipse help](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_core_filebuffers_annotationModelCreation.html?resultof=%22annotation%22%20%22annot%22%20%22model%22%20%22creation%22%20).

Comment: Your blog posts is exactly what I needed, but I can only map the markers to character counts rather than line numbers. Is there a way to identify which character counts I need based on an external line number, or to map a marker to a line number rather than Char_start and char_end?

Comment: Basically the API wants char_start and char_end as the platform opens your file as a stream. You can convert the char_start and char_end to line numbers manually by reading the text until you read char_start/char_end number of characters, and calculate the number of line breaks that far. For backwards read the number of lines, and calculate the number of characters. Or if you use the JFace IDocument API, it has some corresponding methods for automated conversion (if you have a custom editor, you ought to have such interface). I don't remember the correct method name for this.

Comment: Awesome. Lastly, is there a way to effectively make my annotation highlight colors vary based on different data, or do I need to define a new marker for each color I wish to use?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know. There should be a way to solve it: problem markers are translated into warning or error annotations depending on a marker property, but I don't know how it is managed.